# Expressing equal probability on an infinite line with probability axioms

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Is there any way using the usual (Kolmogorov) axioms of probability to describe/model the following situation :

A value $v \in \mathbb{R}$ has an equal probability of being measured anywhere in the interval $(-\infty, +\infty)$. What we want to express is that :

1. The probability of getting *some* value, in other words, some $v \in (-\infty, \infty)$, is 1.
2. If there are two intervals $A$ and $B$, and $|A|=k\ |B|$, then the probability of $v$ being in $A$ is $k$ times the probability of $v$ being in $B$.

When attempting to model it with probability axioms, since the interval of all possible values for $v$ is infinite, each finite interval in $\mathbb{R}$ will have probability $0$. Countably adding the probability of finite intervals to get the entire $\mathbb{R}$ will then still yield $0$, which is not compatible with the axiom that $P(\mathbb{R})=1$. Also, there seems to be no way to express 2 above.

Comment: Your argument is right. There is no such probability measure.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is solid. In fact, given *any* infinite set $X$ for which there is a countably-infinite partition $\mathscr P$ into sets of equal cardinality, there is no uniform probability measure on $X$ making all $\mathscr P$-sets measurable.

Comment: So then how does one model this situation, which can arise as a fairly natural notion - for example, if the value being measured is the position of a particle, then the two conditions essentially say "The particle can be found anywhere, will definitely be found somewhere, and with a chance proportional to the length of your detection device" ?

Comment: One instead uses a *measure*, like the [Lebesgue measure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure). It acts like a probability measure, but with the space having infinite measure.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the source, there are two sets of axioms that are sometimes called "Kolmogorov's axioms."

1. One set of axioms requires that probability be *finitely* additive, i.e., for any finite collection of disjoint events $A_1, \ldots, A_n$, the probability of the union $P(\bigcup_{i \leq n} A_i)$ is equal to the sum $\sum_{i \leq n} P(A_i)$.
2. Often times, however, Kolmogorov's axioms are said to require *countable* additivity, i.e., for any countable collection of disjoint events $\{A_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, the probability of the union $P(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n)$ is equal to the sum $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} P(A_i)$.

The latter condition is obviously strictly stronger than the former.

Your two conditions are possible to fulfil if only finite additivity is required of a probability measure, but they are impossible to satisfy if a probability measure is required to be countably additive.

To see that they cannot be satisfied for a countably additive measure,
note that the intervals $\{[z,z+1): z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ cover the real number line.  By countable additivity, at least one of those intervals must have positive probability if the entire real line has positive probability.  Now if any interval $A$ has positive probability $r$, then the interval $[0,1]$ has probability $1/|A|$ by your second condition.  By finite additivity (which is entailed by countable additivity), it follows that the intervals $[0,1), [1,2), \ldots [M, M+1)$ have probability greater than $1$, where $M$ is the ceiling of $(|A|)+1$.  That's obviously impossible.

If probability is only required to be finitely additive, however, it is possible to define a measure that satisfies your two conditions.  The reason is that one can assign every interval of *finite* length probability zero, and so your second condition is immediately satisfied.  A good source to consult is Savage's *Foundation of Statistics*, which contains a discussion of the importance of finitely additive probability measures.